# How to do dual stack IPv4/IPv6 with virtual hosts on nginx 1.4

Tags: nginx, virtualhost, ipv6, ipv4

I'm using nginx 1.4.1 (now, before it was 1.2.1) and would like to support dual stack (IPv4 and IPv6). I'm always getting `duplicate listen options for xyz` errors from nginx.

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 ipv6only=on default_server;
    server_name domain1;
}
server {
    listen 443 ssl default_server;
    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on default_server;
    server_name domain1;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80 ipv6only=on;
    server_name domain2;
}
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on;
    server_name domain2;
}
```

If I use only `listen 80` I'm getting only IPv4. Otherwise if I use `listen [::]:80` I'm getting only IPv6.

**How to setup nginx 1.4.x to support virtual host dual stack?**

Comment: Use this to find out if it's binding correctly `netstat -nlp | grep nginx`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

<strike>You've used `default_server` in more than one `server` block. This is only meant to be used to define the default virtual host for a given IP address/port combination. So it should appear only once per IP/port pair in your entire configuration. Which host should be the default virtual host is up to you.</strike> (Or you did, until you edited this part out.)

Also, `ipv6only` can appear only once in the entire configuration. Since its default in 1.4 and higher is `on`, you can safely omit it entirely.

Comment: Removing `ipv6only` solved the problem. Strange error behaviour.